# Is it possible to block redistribution of a linux or unix distribution?

Tags: distributions

Suppose I want to develop a Unix/Linux distribution, and I don't want that any other person or entity redistribute it.

I.e., they will be able to see the source code but won't be able to redistribute it.

Is it possible?

Comment: "_Suppose I want to develop a Unix/Linux distribution, and I don't want that any other person or entity [to] redistribute it._" - you probably ought to read the GPL first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal questions regarding Open-Source software. As such, it should probably be posted either on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com) or [OpenSource SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @roaima hm, you can perfectly well do a GPL-free Linux distro, aside from the kernel. A lot of businesses are doing it. In fact, there's probably more devices these days running such no-GPL userland linuxes than there is running GNU/Linuxes (your Android phone, with a high chance, your router, your smart camera, and if you're well off, your car).  Yes, you still have to give out the kernel source code, and can't stop anyone from redistributing it, but that's probably the least important part about what constitutes a "distribution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible, for source code you write: several Unix systems were available with source licenses in the past, with licenses that didn’t allow further redistribution.

If you’re redistributing source code others wrote, you’ll have to abide by the applicable licenses, which may not allow you to restrict redistribution.

You should really talk to a lawyer about this.